# What are the differences between choice and multichoice in LaTeX3?

Tags: expl3, latex3

When I was reading the `interface3.pdf` or the `source3.pdf` about the key-value part, I got confused when I saw `<key>.choice:` and `<key>.multichoice:`.

The explanations and examples of these two command are very similar and from the information given, I thought `<key>.choice:` can do the job of `<key>.multichoice:`, so what is the "extraordinary" function of `<key>.multichoice:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `.choice:` is a key which accepts exactly one value, whereas `.multichoice:` means a key can be multi-valued. So if a user gives

```latex
some-key = a , some-key = b
```

a `.choice:` key will be set only to `b`, whereas a `.multichoice:` key is set to `a,b`. More typically, a user might give

```latex
some-key = {a,b}
```

which would (almost certainly) be an error for a `.choice:` key but which would apply both `a` and `b` for `.multichoice:`.